# Header file for accessing components globally in library

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In my project I have a header file which contains only functions which are put into a namespace, the purpose of these functions is to be used from another class of the framework I'm working on, or from client code.

Does this code follow best practices? How can I efficiently just keep such data?

```
#pragma once

#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

namespace lwlog::datetime
{
    std::string get_chrono(std::string format)
    {
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&in_time_t), format.c_str());
        return ss.str();
    }

    std::string get_time()                      { return get_chrono("%H:%M:%S"); }
    std::string get_date()                      { return get_chrono("%Y-%m-%d"); }
    std::string get_date_short()                { return get_chrono("%m/%d/%y"); }
    std::string get_second()                    { return get_chrono("%S"); }
    std::string get_minute()                    { return get_chrono("%M"); }
    std::string get_hour_24()                   { return get_chrono("%H"); }
    std::string get_hour_12()                   { return get_chrono("%I"); }
    std::string get_weekday()                   { return get_chrono("%A"); }
    std::string get_weekday_abbreviated()       { return get_chrono("%a"); }
    std::string get_day()                       { return get_chrono("%d"); }
    std::string get_month()                     { return get_chrono("%m"); }
    std::string get_month_name()                { return get_chrono("%B"); }
    std::string get_month_name_abbreviated()    { return get_chrono("%b"); }
    std::string get_year()                      { return get_chrono("%Y"); }
    std::string get_year_short()                { return get_chrono("%y"); }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried including this header from multiple sources? I suspect that it wouldn't link. `get_chrono` is not a template function, so you'd be double-defining it.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274312/defining-c-functions-inside-header-files/25274371

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: Are functions like `get_minute()` and `get_second()` of actual use to any code?  I've never seen a need for getting single components from a timepoint, without needing one or more other components from the same timepoint (rather than from some future timepont).

Comment: Yes they are needed for a logging framework pattern formatter

Comment: I fixed the title - since that's not strictly about getting time, it's about the more abstract picture - is it okay to have a header file for globally accessing functions

Comment: I still don't understand: what use is the "second" value without the "minute" value?

Comment: Code Review is *never* about the "abstract picture" - we specifically ask for *real code, in context*.

Comment: I'm well informed, and that's why I have posted a snippet of code which I'm interested in, yet I don't want to give out the impression it's strictly regarded about time.

Comment: I need a second because one can use a minute and second in their pattern, or just output time in a more specific way.

Answer (score 3):

- As noted by commenters, you will get multiple definition errors if you try to include this header in multiple translation units. The functions must be marked `inline`, or the header file reduced to the declarations, with the definitions placed in a separate source file.
- The `std::string format` argument is copied unnecessarily as it is passed by value. It should be passed by `const&` instead. (Or replaced with `std::string_view`).
- The difference between all these functions is the format string. As such, we don't really need the functions at all. We can define the format strings as constants, and the user can pass the one they need to `get_chrono`.
- `get_chrono` is probably not the best name for the function. Maybe `format_time_now`, or `format_time`.
- The function would be much less restrictive if the time were passed as an argument. It can then be used for formatting other times than `now`.
- Note also that in the original code, if we wanted to call `get_second` and `get_minute` for one point in time (say for some custom output format), we can't! Because `now` will have changed between the calls, and we might end up with incorrect output.

Comment: How can this problem with now be tackled?

Comment: The user should call `now` themselves and store the time in a local variable, and then they can pass it as an argument to the function as many times as they like.

Answer (score 2):

There are many useless functions here, because individual time components aren't much use separately.  For example, `get_second()` is unlikely to be any use to anyone, as users generally want the minutes, too.  It won't work to separately call `get_minute()`, because that returns the "minute" component of a *different time-point* (that of the second call).  So the API presented is likely to encourage user errors.

I advise removing all the functions that return individual components.

There exist single formats for time and date - use `%T` instead of `%H:%M:%S`, and `%F` instead of `%Y-%m-%d`.  (Note that `%D` superficially appears like it might be the short date formate, but it's broken because it puts month first).

If we're to use this for logging, then `std::localtime` is a poor choice, as this has jumps and ambiguities around daylight savings changes.  `std::gmtime` is more suitable for this purpose, as it's monotonic on a well-administered system.

Oh, and you'll need your functions to have *static linkage*, so you don't get conflicts when two or more translation units both define the functions.